# What should be the starting salary for a freshly graduated UX Designer?

Tags: hiring

I am thinking of offering UX design position to this person who has been working with me as intern for past 6 months. She has completed Master in Human Factors. I like her work and she is a hard worker. We are based in MA. What salary should I offer?

Answer (score 2):

According to the AIGA salary survey in 2014, the national median pay for a UX Designer was around $80k. Since she is at an entry-level position, it shouldn't be that high.
(http://designsalaries.aiga.org/#position/user-experience-designer)

According to PayScale, the average entry-level UX Designer is around $69k.
(http://www.payscale.com/research/US/Job=User_Experience_Designer/Salary/9c28463c/Entry-Level-Boston-MA)

If you look at a Junior UX Designer in Boston's average pay on Glassdoor, you'll come in around $60k.
(https://www.glassdoor.com/Salaries/boston-junior-user-experience-designer-salary-SRCH_IL.0,6_IM109_KO7,38.htm)

These sites are not always 100% accurate, but they at least give you an idea. I'd say between $55k-$65k is fair, but you know how much she is worth to you much more than I do.

Hope this helps!